# Return REGEX values in the right order

Tags: python, regex

I am facing a little challenge here. Basically I have some complex strings from which I need to extract numerical values. I managed to write down a piece of code that retrieve the numerical values, unfortunately they seem to be returned in the wrong order (the order matters a lot here).

Here is an example of strings I am dealing with (they are contained in a dataframe):

```
Singles Round of 16.
01:33:55
D. Altmaier
4
4
M. Kecmanovic
6
6
 Game Set and Match Miomir Kecmanovic. Miomir Kecmanovic wins the match 6-4 6-4 .
```

As you understood, this is a tennis score. My goal is to isolate the games won by each player in two separated variables like this

```
p1_score = 4 4
p2_score = 6 6
```

So anything between Altmaier name & Kecmanovic name is p1_score and anything after Kecmanovic & before the last sentence is p2_score

Right now I am using the following code to handle such matter

```
def extract_player_scores(row):
    
    #Score is the column in which my raw string is contained
    parts = row['score'].split()
    numeric_parts = [part for part in parts if part.isdigit()]

    #Trying to break down the string into two piececs according to their character position 
    p1_scores = ' '.join(numeric_parts[::2])
    p2_scores = ' '.join(numeric_parts[1::2])

    return pd.Series([p1_scores, p2_scores])

df_final[['p1_score', 'p2_score']] = df_final.apply(extract_player_scores, axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, this code tend to mix the values position and I am getting `p1_score = 4 6` instead of `p1_score = 4 4`

What would you suggest to retrieve all those values in the right order?

Thanks a lot for the help here

Comment: it's already sorted in `numeric_parts`, why are you jumping weirdly through it?

Comment: What do you think `[::2]` does?

Answer (score 0):

The slices with step 2 (`::2`) make no sense, since the input has the scores of player 1 in one series without interruptions. Same for player 2.

I would also suggest using `splitlines()` instead of `split()`, since the scores you are interested in are each on their own line. The first half of the found numbers belong to player 1, and the second half to player 2:

```
scores = [line for line in row['score'].splitlines() if line.isdigit()]
n = len(scores) // 2
p1_scores = " ".join(scores[:n])
p2_scores = " ".join(scores[n:])
```

Comment: @diggusbickus, it was, but the author didn't format that block correctly so that linebreaks were rendered as spaces.